# Embedding mov in HTML5. Validation problem!

Tags: html, attributes, doctype, w3c-validation

I'm trying to embed a .mov video in a web page whose DOCTYPE is HTML5, the code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
QT_WritePoster_XHTML('Click to Play', '...', '...',
                '400', '300', '',
                'controller', 'true',
                'autoplay', 'true',
                'bgcolor', 'black',
                'scale', 'aspect');
</script>
<noscript>
<object width="400" height="300" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
    <param name="src" value="..." />
    <param name="href" value="..." />
    <param name="target" value="myself" />
    <param name="controller" value="false" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
    <param name="scale" value="aspect" />
    <embed width="400" height="300" type="video/quicktime"  pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
        src="..."
        href="..."
        target="myself"
        controller="false"
        autoplay="false"
        scale="aspect" />
</object>
</noscript>
```

All works fine but I've a validation problem because in the HTML5 standard the tag "object" hasn't "classid" and "codebase" attributes!

Is there any way to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validating against HTML5 is of dubious value at present, because it is not stable. If it works (and it will), just go for it.

I believe the idea is that you use the type attribute instead of the classid attribute but it is not at all clear whether it provides the same level of control.

There a bug record in the HTML5 bugzilla relating to this (http://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=7694), if you do not believe that the type attribute is a satisfactory replacement for classid, you may like to contribute to that bug record.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to embed a mov in a HTML5 page you should use the video tag. It is a lot less code too...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but FF has still some big problems with the "video" tag.

Comment: True, but older versions of FF (and other browsers) have problems with styling HTML5 tags. So if you are not using HTML5 tags, because they don't work, why are you using the HTML5 doctype?